# How to access beanstalk environment URL from EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My web application deployed via Elastic Beanstalk also reads from an SQS queue.  As part of my blue/green deployment approach, I'd prefer only the environment actively serving production HTTP requests to pull messages from the queue.  My original thought is to have the app periodically check the URL of the Elastic Beanstalk environment into which it is deployed and only read from SQS if the URL matches a certain pattern (indicating it is the current "production" environment).

How, from an app running on an Elastic Beanstalk deployed EC2 instance, can I determine its environment URL?  (Or is there a better way to accomplish this goal?)

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to look for an environment variable that you can control via the Elastic Beanstalk console. If the value of your environment variable is something like "production", your app should do production-y things.